# minMax python RISK strategy AI

Tags: python, oop, artificial-intelligence, minmax

I'm trying to get an AI working for a turn-based strategy game (like RISK). I'm a little new to AI programming, but I think my issue might just be passing the wrong parameter or something, either way, if anybody could tell me what's wrong, or anything else that will pose an issue with using minMax to solve this problem; answers would be greatly appreciated.
The problem, I think, is that somewhere along the line (possibly in the passing of 'newBoard') 'newBoard' gets overwritten to a large integer value

```
##sectors array takes this form: [['Canada',[300,200],'',0,[1,2,12]],['Greenland',[600,120],'',0,[0,7]],['USA',[360,300],'',0,[0,3]],['Central America',[360,410],'',0,[2,4]],['South America',[480,510],'',0,[3,5]],['Brazil',[560,580],'',0,[4,6,15]],['Argentina',[490,700],'',0,[5]],['West Europe',[760,260],'',0,[1,8,9,15]],['East Europe',[875,260],'',0,[7,9,10,11,13]],['Scandanavia',[870,170],'',0,[7,8,10]],['West Russia',[970,220],'',0,[8,9,11,13]],['Central Russia',[1160,210],'',0,[10,12,13,19]],['Far East',[1350,220],'',0,[0,11,19]],['Central Asia',[1030,320],'',0,[8,10,11,14,18]],['Middle East',[970,380],'',0,[13,16]],['North Africa',[760,400],'',0,[5,7,16]],['Central Africa',[880,470],'',0,[15,14,17]],['South Africa',[880,610],'',0,[16,18]],['India',[1125,390],'',0,[13,17,19]],['East Asia',[1225,360],'',0,[11,12,13,18,20]],['Indonesia',[1290,510],'',0,[19,21]],['Australia',[1360,640],'',0,[20]]]
```

where data in each sublist is: name, position on the screen (unimportant here), player controling it (randomized), population, other sectors it connects to

```
class Node(object):

    def populateChildren(self,player,board):
        print("start conditions: ",player,board)
        newBoard=board
        start=randomStart(board, player)
        if self.depth>-1:
            ##[base case]
            for i in board[start][4]:
                newBoard[i][3]=(board[start][3]-board[i][3])
                newBoard[start][3]=1
                self.children.append(Node((self.depth)-1,-self.player,newBoard,self.treeVal(newBoard)))
        else:
            print("RECURSION END")

    def treeVal(self,board):
        if checkWin(board)==True:
            return maxsize*self.player
        elif checkWin:
            return maxsize*-self.player
        return 0

    def __init__(self,depth,player,newBoard,value=0):
        self.depth=depth
        self.player=player
        self.value=value
        self.children=[]
        self.populateChildren(player,newBoard)

def minMax(node,depth,player):
    if depth==0 or abs(node.value)==maxsize:
        return node.value
    bestValue=maxsize*-playerNum
    for i in range(0,5):
        child=node.children[i]
        value=MinMax(child,depth-1,-playerNum)
        if abs(maxsize*playerNum-value)<abs(maxsize*playerNum-bestValue):
            bestValue=value
    return bestValue

def AIMove(Node,sectors):
   newBoard=sectors
   currentPlayer=-1
   depth=10
   looks=0
   while looks<6:
      Node.player=-1
      node=Node(depth,currentPlayer,newBoard,value=0)
      bestChoice=-100
      bestValue=currentPlayer*maxsize
      for i in range(len(node.children)):
         child=node.children[i]
         value=MinMax(child,depth,currentPlayer)
         if (abs(currentPlayer*maxsize-value)<=abs(currentPlayer*maxsize-bestValue)):
            bestValue=value
            bestChoice=i
      bestChoice+=1
      looks+=1
```

If I have left anything out, I'm more than happy to update the thread with any required information, thank you.

Comment: There are too many things obviously broken in this code to try to give a detailed answer, but I think a big question is what is `newBoard` supposed to do? Why are you passing around the same board instead of making *actually new* boards? I'd expect you want to do a `copy.deepcopy` of your current board almost every time.

Comment: Good point, I've pruned the extra board out now, so it's basically looping but making no real progress, I'll update the thread, cheers